# Waiting till call back completes Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

My situation is like this, I have a server like this and inside I am calling another callback function which gets multiple values:

```
var http = require('http'); 
var server = http.createServer(req,resp) {
     var finalVal = "";

     consumer.on('message',function(message) {
         finalVal = message;
         console.log(finalVal);
     });

     resp.end(finalVal);
});
```

My finalVal should display all the multiple values it fetches and send it as a response, but problem is it's sending only first value where as console.log displays all the values. I do understand that by the time consumer.on ends response would have committed. Can someone please help me how to handle this scenario since I'm very new to Node.js ? Currently due to heavy deadlines I don't have time to read full information about callbacks. But defnitely I would take time to learn about callbacks.

**Edit**: Here `consumer.on` calls multiple times till it fetches all the data from backend, I need to send all those data in a final response. I am using `node-kafka` to consume to kafka messages.

Comment: put `resp.end(finalVal);` just after `console.log`.

Comment: I did, it displays only the first value.. remaining other values are ignored. But it displays in the console.

Comment: Why the downvote? Tell me at-least so that I can improve the question.

Comment: Here multiple value means, `consumer.on` is called multiple times until it gets all the data.

Comment: Is there no `end` event? What's consumer? You should also be using `finalval += message` as what you have now is overwriting your variable.

Comment: @BenFortune I am using node-kafka, to consume kafka messages

Comment: I think node-kakfa gives just `client` or it provides server side api also

Comment: The problem is that library doesn't provide any such event called `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be an `end` event or something like that which tells that `consumer` has finished the message, you can use that

I am not sure what is consumer here, but in most of cases we go with something like bellow

```
var finalVal = '';

consumer.on('message',function(message) {
     finalVal += message; // So on each message you will just update the final value
     console.log(finalVal);
 });

consumer.on('end',function(){ // And at the end send the response
     resp.end(finalVal);
});
```

Comment: There is no such event called `end` in the library :(